# How do I show multiple locations in Google Maps?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple longtitude and attitude data and I want to show them in the google map with pins.

How to use the google map API to do this?

Answer (score 9):

You iterate over your array, and create a new `Marker` instance for each pair. It's simple:

```
<script>
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.378051, -3.435973),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 8
    });

    var locations = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.97784, -1.612916),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.378051, -3.435973])
        // and additional coordinates, just add a new item
    ];

    locations.forEach(function (location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works for any number of latitude/longitude pairs; just add a new item to the `locations` array.

Comment: Good idea! My case is that I have bunch of location names which need to translated to coordinates. Those location names are extracted from documents whic are search results of search engines. The input are free text of documents and the output is a map with pins showing those location names. This javascript only takes array (fixed database) as input, can it be done in the above situation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are your location names is any specific format, or are they literally lifted as text from search engine results in whatever format they were written in the original documents?

Comment: For example, in the search result of google, there are text documents which may contain geo-locations. First I want to find those locations and then maybe call web service to translate names to cordinates stored somewhere if possible. After that, calling Google maps API to show those names as pins in the map.

Comment: So you want to replicate Google's search results page?

Comment: Kind of. I need to find geo-location names in one result document with the database of geo-location names. This is the basis of everything. Any idea?

Comment: If it's user-submitted data then it could be in any format; that's going to take some serious data-mining skills and something that exceeds what can be described in a Stack Overflow comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
   var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);

    // Create our "tiny" marker icon
    var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
    blueIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";

    // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
    markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };

    // Add 10 markers to the map at random locations
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var point = new GLatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
        southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
      map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point, markerOptions));
    }
```

I have taken this example from google API documentation where they have shown how you can use lat ong to show things

Refer this for details

[Showing markers using Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Icons_overview)

Though i have used v2 which has been deprecated but concept to use will be more or less same

Comment: I am currently trying to extract geo-location names in the result documents returned by search engine and display them like pins in the map. So there are location names I have which need to be translated to coordinates and then call google map to display the image. Any idea?

Comment: can you elaborate your requirement since in your question you told you have latitude an longitude so its really not difficult to call Google map service and passing a point to it, point is nothing but being calculated based on latitude and longitude.

Comment: For example, in the search result of google, there are text documents which may contain geo-locations. First I want to find those locations and then maybe call web service to translate names to cordinates stored somewhere if possible. After that, calling Google maps API to show those names as pins in the map.