# How do i get multiple coordinates on a google maps static api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, google-maps-static-api

I am pulling out information from the google places API I want to be able to show all the coordinates that I've pulled on one map v.s. having multiple maps on a page (as shown below). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

```
<%@c.each do |p|%>
<ul>
    <li><%= image_tag("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{p.lat},#{p.lng}&zoom=15&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
    &markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C#{p.lat},#{p.lng}&sensor=true")%></li>
    <li><%=p.name%></li>
    <li><%=p.rating%></li>
    <li><%p.lat%></li>
    <li><%p.lng%></li>
</ul>   
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you essentially need the multiple `ul` tags to align with each other.

Essentially you would need to give a fixed width to your ul element and apply a float. Here I have assumed that you would like three maps side-by-side.

**The CSS code for it is:**

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding:1.5%;
}
ul img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

**or if you prefer SCSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding:1.5%;
    li {
        img {
            max-width:100%;
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to see how this would look, check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/dheer/Ltxzj/2/

Note: If you are adding this to your rails app you may want to assign a new class to the ul tag as styling the current code may affect other design elements.

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer made by Martin Bean in this thread:
[How do I show multiple locations in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264117/how-to-show-multiple-location-in-google-map)
which uses the google maps javascript api. As seen in that example, you should just add Markers to the map from your coordinates (in that case he uses a bunch of coordinates that you should load from your model).