# Pass latitude/longitude to Google Maps activity and show more than one location in Android and Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Is it possible to launch google maps activity and pass several latitude/longitude variables so several locations are mapped inside the map? I am able to show one location with this code, but how do I add more parameters?

```
 String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", f11, f22);
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
 startActivity(intent);
```

But is it possible to show more locations at once? Should I use mapview and how?
Thanks.

Comment: create arraylist of lat long and pass that to map activity and set it using for loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264117/how-do-i-show-multiple-locations-in-google-maps

Comment: as far as i know built in api don't display more than one location at a time. Instead of that you can use MapView.

Comment: yes you can do it with help of loop ...